# How to remove TimePicker (calendar) buttons (now and done) in jsf Primefaces

Tags: calendar, primefaces, timepicker

I am dealing with JSF calendar and I want to do my work in Turkish. But when I add TimePicker to my calendar the "now" and "done" buttons are shown and they are in English (like DateTime example on http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/calendarTime.jsf). I want to change the language of the buttons or remove them. Any idea how to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of PF do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize the labels by providing a locale and a localization javascript.

You can grab one of the localization javascripts from the [primefaces wiki](http://wiki.primefaces.org/display/Components/PrimeFaces+Locales).
After that try the following:

```
<h:outputScript name=”path_to_your_translations.js” />
<p:calendar value="#{calendarBean.date1}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" locale="tr" />
```

Comment: It worked very well, I didn't know that we have to write javascript in order to use locale, even user guide doesn't include this information. Thank you.

Comment: Nice solution +1. Just in case you will ever need to hide something you can do it like this (int this case) `button.ui-datepicker-current { display: none; } ` in your css. Just check for the styling class of element in user guide.